# Вопрос по Delphi Contols

Tags: delphi

Не подскажите можно ли сделать вот так:

```
TImage(Form1.Controls[2]).Picture := nil;
```

я заранее проверил по имени контрола, что он `Timage`;

или же можно делать только так:

```
TImage(FindComponent('Image1')).Picture := nil;
```

Или еще как вариант можно ли делать так ?

```
With TImage(Form1.Controls[2])do
begin
....
....
end;
```

Comment: Сделать то можно (все 3 варианта), но за каждый из вариантов будут пинать ногами в продакшене. А цель какая?

Answer (score 3):

Мне кажется, обращение по индексу -- это не очень хорошо, ведь индекс ничего не говорит о *намерении* вашего кода. Ну и индекс может поменяться, если вы (или ваш последователь в проекте) добавите ещё контролы. Лучше обращаться к контролу по имени.

Кстати, я бы придумал имя более осмысленное, чем `Image1`: вы среди ночи не скажете, чем отличается `Image1` от `Image2`, а вот `Image_UserAvatar` от `Image_CountryFlag` точно отличите.

В WPF есть возможность адресовать контролы в окне по именам (для вашего случая было бы `Form1.Image1`), причём в этом случае каст не нужен -- если такая возможность есть и в Delphi, лучше пользоваться ей.

Comment: ну спасибо конечно про название, но я привел просто пример, называются они понятнее ( по крайней мере для меня )
По поводу индекса, я заранее проверяю данный контрол на совпадение имени. ну и я похоже зря не сказал что я динамически создаю контролы соответственно не могу обратиться Form1.Image1

Comment: @Jericho: А если вы добавляете что-то динамически, то может быть есть смысл запоминать в специальной переменной или массиве? То ест; например если вы добавляете 100 картинок, то просто заведите поле -- массив картинок, и вместо того, чтобы лезть в child-элементы `Form1` просто берите их из массива. Сразу будет и типизация, и ошибки отловит компилятор.

Comment: К тому же можно использовать дженерики, к примеру TObjectList<T>, после очистки списка - все объекты удалятся. Это уже в зависимости от нужд автора.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте выражения **is** и **as**

Пример:

```
for i:= 0 to Form1.ControlsCount - 1 do
begin
  if (Form1.Controls[I] is TImage) then
    (Form1.Controls[I] as TImage).Picture := nil;
end;
```

Если вы будите формировать динамически список TImage - записывайте их TList< T> TObjectList< T>. Тогда и перебор можно осуществить по текущему списку.

Answer (score -1):

Вот так можно

```
With Form1.Controls[2]do
begin
...
...
...
end;
```

Comment: Эм, если написать так как вы то он не унаследует свойства TImage.

Comment: Возможно я ошибаюсь и вы правы, сейчас проверить не могу нету под рукой компа.